# Storing schedules and sessions (not web) in SQL for querying

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building an application that looks at people’s session times and schedules and am trying to determine the best way of storing queryable data.

I have two datasets that I need join together using start and end times.

A very simplified example:
Table 1: Events

```
    CREATE TABLE EventsData (
    EventID INT,
    VenueID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    EventStartTime TIME,
    EventEndTime TIME
    )
```

Table 2: Sessions

```
    CREATE TABLE SessionData (
    SessionID INT,
    PersonID INT,
    VenueID INT,
    SessionDate DATE,
    SessionStartTime TIME,
    SessionEndTime TIME
    )
```

The way I’m currently going about doing this is to have a linking table that contains a minute by minute breakdown with the Person and Event IDs. Kind of like this...

```
    CREATE TABLE Event2Session (
    SessionID INT,
    Minute DATETIME,
    EventID
    )
```

This will make life a lot easier for querying data but this table (albeit very thin) will get very large very quickly!

On its current data size the linking table is about 2 million lines a day which isn't the end of the world but still bigger than I’d like.

One of the main reasons for doing it like this is so that there will be times where people will have multiple overlapping sessions. For example an event typically lasts 15 - 30 mins and a person’s sessions can vary from 1 mins to 200 mins.

Do any of you lovely people have any clever suggestions I should look into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of storing each minutes, you could store the starting and ending minute, this will provide 1 entry for someone who stayed 200 minutes

Comment: You already have the Person info in the session info, so all the information is there already

Comment: @Cid Thanks for the input, we currently have this in the SessionData. I'm using the linking table to perform queries such as, how many people attended Event A.

Comment: Remove the `Minute` from `Event2Session`, you already have this information in `SessionData`

Comment: @Cid Good shout, that would at least save me another column in the linking table

Comment: And that would save you a bunch of useless entries. By useless, I mean duplicated datas stored. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using